# Filter SQL query where one column is a json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, filter

I have a column in SQL that has a JSON formatted data inside of it. For example, lets call this column JSON and the first input would be

```json
{
  "ID" :123, 
  "NAME": NULL, 
  "FINISH": "MATTE"
}
```

How can I filter this column and only display values that don't have a NULL input in a variable such as "NAME"?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: It's an SQL database. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this so not sure if that answered your question.

Comment: There's no SQL database. SQL is just a language to interact with database management systems(DBMS). Can you tag your DBMS please ?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: SSMS is still not a database, just a front-end. But since it can only connect to SQL Server, that narrows it down. :P Now, what does `SELECT @@VERSION` give? That's important to determine if you have native JSON support.

Comment: It gives back Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP3 GDR (KB5014355)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the following approach:

```sql
select *
from <your_table>
where json_value(<your_json_column>, '$.name') is not null;
```

In the query above, you'd only need to change `<your_table>` for the actual name of the table, and `<your_json_column>` for the actual name of the JSON column.